# How to connect WD NAS hard drive to Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04

I bought a WD40EFAX Sаtа  6Gb/s HX AT 500 NAS vare 3.0. I tried to connect it with a cable, but no folders are visible. What terminal commands do I need to run to be able to use this drive?

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 186.83 MiB, 195887104 bytes, 382592 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 185.34 MiB, 194338816 bytes, 379568 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 114.68 MiB, 120229888 bytes, 234824 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 147.58 MiB, 154738688 bytes, 302224 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 132.76 MiB, 139186176 bytes, 271848 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 16.21 MiB, 16990208 bytes, 33184 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 17.10 MiB, 18845696 bytes, 36808 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdb: 1.84 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD2003FYPS-2
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xb13f313b

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1             2048 3288800184 3288798137   1.5T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2       3289853950 3907028991  617175042 294.3G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb3       3288801280 3289851903    1050624   513M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sdb5       3890536448 3907028991   16492544   7.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb6       3289853952 3890536447  600682496 286.4G 83 Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/sda: 111.81 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 840 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000805c8

Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048    718847    716800   350M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       718848 234438655 233719808 111.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Disk /dev/sdc: 1.84 TiB, 2000398933504 bytes, 3907029167 sectors
Disk model: FA GoFlex Desk  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa4b57300

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1          63 3907024127 3907024065  1.8T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Disk /dev/loop9: 99.45 MiB, 104267776 bytes, 203648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 55.5 MiB, 58183680 bytes, 113640 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 55.52 MiB, 58204160 bytes, 113680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop12: 61.85 MiB, 64835584 bytes, 126632 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop13: 61.93 MiB, 64913408 bytes, 126784 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop14: 169.67 MiB, 177897472 bytes, 347456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop15: 612 KiB, 626688 bytes, 1224 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop16: 169.64 MiB, 177868800 bytes, 347400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop17: 277.4 MiB, 290496512 bytes, 567376 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop18: 391.28 MiB, 410279936 bytes, 801328 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop19: 162.89 MiB, 170778624 bytes, 333552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop20: 164.78 MiB, 172761088 bytes, 337424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop21: 219 MiB, 229638144 bytes, 448512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop22: 219 MiB, 229638144 bytes, 448512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop23: 242.35 MiB, 254115840 bytes, 496320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop24: 247.93 MiB, 259948544 bytes, 507712 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop25: 140 KiB, 143360 bytes, 280 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop26: 132 KiB, 135168 bytes, 264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop27: 65.1 MiB, 68259840 bytes, 133320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop28: 65.22 MiB, 68378624 bytes, 133552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop29: 63.6 MiB, 66674688 bytes, 130224 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop30: 67.29 MiB, 70549504 bytes, 137792 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop31: 290.59 MiB, 304689152 bytes, 595096 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop32: 260.73 MiB, 273375232 bytes, 533936 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop33: 323.52 MiB, 339222528 bytes, 662544 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop34: 62.101 MiB, 66043904 bytes, 128992 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop35: 150.17 MiB, 157462528 bytes, 307544 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop36: 50.98 MiB, 53432320 bytes, 104360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop37: 54.24 MiB, 56872960 bytes, 111080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop38: 43.28 MiB, 45371392 bytes, 88616 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop39: 43.44 MiB, 45543424 bytes, 88952 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop40: 295.62 MiB, 309968896 bytes, 605408 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop41: 295.73 MiB, 310079488 bytes, 605624 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop42: 110.5 MiB, 115855360 bytes, 226280 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sde: 3.65 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD40EFAX-68J
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

And

```
$ sudo lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0 186.8M  1 loop /snap/audacity/934
loop1    7:1    0 185.3M  1 loop /snap/audacity/922
loop2    7:2    0 114.7M  1 loop /snap/b1freearchiver/2
loop3    7:3    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop4    7:4    0 147.6M  1 loop /snap/chromium/1864
loop5    7:5    0 132.8M  1 loop /snap/chromium/1878
loop6    7:6    0  16.2M  1 loop /snap/chromium-ffmpeg/23
loop7    7:7    0    18M  1 loop /snap/chromium-ffmpeg/24
loop9    7:9    0  99.4M  1 loop /snap/core/11993
loop10   7:10   0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2253
loop11   7:11   0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2284
loop12   7:12   0  61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1242
loop13   7:13   0  61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1270
loop14   7:14   0 169.7M  1 loop /snap/digikam/49
loop15   7:15   0   612K  1 loop /snap/curl-httpie/2
loop16   7:16   0 169.6M  1 loop /snap/digikam/50
loop17   7:17   0   277M  1 loop /snap/gimp/380
loop18   7:18   0 391.3M  1 loop /snap/gimp/383
loop19   7:19   0 162.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
loop20   7:20   0 164.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
loop21   7:21   0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
loop22   7:22   0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77
loop23   7:23   0 242.4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/76
loop24   7:24   0 247.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/87
loop25   7:25   0   140K  1 loop /snap/gtk2-common-themes/13
loop26   7:26   0   132K  1 loop /snap/gtk2-common-themes/9
loop27   7:27   0  65.1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
loop28   7:28   0  65.2M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1519
loop29   7:29   0  63.6M  1 loop /snap/handbrake-jz/142
loop30   7:30   0  67.3M  1 loop /snap/jupyter/6
loop31   7:31   0 290.6M  1 loop /snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18/4
loop32   7:32   0 260.7M  1 loop /snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/32
loop33   7:33   0 323.5M  1 loop /snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-core20/14
loop34   7:34   0    63M  1 loop /snap/okular/108
loop35   7:35   0 150.2M  1 loop /snap/okular/109
loop36   7:36   0    51M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/547
loop37   7:37   0  54.2M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/558
loop38   7:38   0  43.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/14295
loop39   7:39   0  43.4M  1 loop /snap/snapd/14549
loop40   7:40   0 295.6M  1 loop /snap/vlc/2288
loop41   7:41   0 295.7M  1 loop /snap/vlc/2344
loop42   7:42   0 110.5M  1 loop /snap/core/12603
sda      8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   350M  0 part 
└─sda2   8:2    0 111.5G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   1.5T  0 part /media/varo-20/2TB
├─sdb2   8:18   0     1K  0 part 
├─sdb3   8:19   0   513M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sdb5   8:21   0   7.9G  0 part 
└─sdb6   8:22   0 286.4G  0 part /
sdc      8:32   0   1.8T  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   0   1.8T  0 part /media/varo-20/Seagate Replica
sde      8:64   0   3.7T  0 disk
```

I used these cables to connect to Sata 1

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01MZBDDPM?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2_dt_b_product_details](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MZBDDPM)

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07JW9RMTG?ref=ppx_yo2_dt_b_product_details&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JW9RMTG)

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `sudo fdisk -l` and `sudo lsblk`, please? Thanks! Also, how are you connecting it? If via SATA, make sure you connected both data and power. If via a USB to SATA adapter, it may not work unless it also has a dedicated power supply (i.e., a little thing you plug into the wall as well). [Here's an example](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07JGT17B8/) of a USB-SATA adapter that has a power supply (no affiliation, use at your own risk).

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy. From the output above, I think it is `/dev/sde`. But **please double-check** before you do this. Open GParted. In the top-right, select your NAS drive. **All data on it will be erased**. So double check that you've selected the correct one. Once the correct drive is selected in the top-right, delete every partition on that drive (right-click on each one, and delete it). Specifically, delete everything inside the red box (I drew the red box, it isn't part of the UI):
[image: Screenshot of GParted]
(I took the screenshot from the GParted website)

Once you've deleted all the partitions on that disk, double-check that the right disk is selected. If you're sure that you have the right one, hit `Apply`, and wait for it to finish. Once it's done, right-click where all the partitions were, and make a new one. Set the filesystem to ext4, and accept the rest of the defaults. Press "Add", then hit Apply. Congratulations, you've now made one partition for all your stuff. Once it finishes creating the partition, run `lsblk`, and you will see your new partition as something like `/dev/sde1`. Open a terminal, run `sudo mkdir /mnt/wd_nas`, and then run `sudo mount /dev/sde1 /mnt/wd_nas` (replacing `/dev/sde1` with the correct partition), and then when you go to `/mnt/wd_nas`, files you put there will appear on your drive. To un-mount it, do `sudo umount /mnt/wd_nas`. You will have to mount it whenever you reboot.